# How often do Chrome extensions automatically update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, updates, auto-update

When I push a new version of a Chrome extension to the Chrome Web Store, how long after the new version becomes visible in the Chrome Web Store will it take for current users to be automatically updated to the new version?

I pushed an update about six hours ago, but the extension hasn't updated for me yet. The Chrome docs are unclear.

Comment: If your question is why it is not auto updating. This typically happens once in several hours. The precise frequency is unknown as mentioned in [archive of `https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171211000256/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate). And in practice I've actually had to restart to see it update or ended up updating them manually.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 3rd party publication cycles.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

##### Automatic updates

Currently, this defaults to 5 hours (based on [the code here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/common/constants.h;l=99)), which can be overridden by launching Chrome with the `extensions-update-frequency` command-line parameter, which is the frequency in seconds.

##### Manual updates

You can go to `chrome://extensions`, tick the "Developer mode" checkbox at the top right, then press the "Update Extensions Now" button.

##### Documentation

The Chrome documentation ([archive of `https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171211000256/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate)) doesn't specify this 5 hour value though, so it could change in future versions without notice:

> *Every few hours*, the browser checks whether any installed extensions
> or apps have an update URL. For each one, it makes a request to that
> URL looking for an update manifest XML file.

Answer (score 17):

Restarting the browser and OS didn't help. Eventually, the extension updated itself, but it took at least 48 hours.

Comment: This is not an answer to the stated question, even if you accept it as such.

Comment: Even if this doesn't answer the question, I can see that you're the one who wrote the question, and I've been wondering the same. Now we know an upper-bound for autoupdate is at least 2 days. Thank you, this is useful for me.